# Creating a master page for a xamarin.android application

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

[image]

I am completely new to Xamarin and started learning with xamarin.android. I am working on an app and need to create a master page where items 1,2,3,5,6 in the image above will be clickable images that will return data and display in section 4. 
How can I create a master page like this? The only section that will be changing is section 4 when users click on the other icons. Some directions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is explained here: 
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Hanselman.Forms

Comment: Thanks. I am not using xamarin forms though. I guess this uses xamarin forms. I am using xamarin.android

Comment: Sorry, I though it was with Forms.  You can also find a solution with Mvvmcross here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Android-Support/Fragments  and the code could be translated without MvvmCross.

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at the new link you sent, very confusing. Not sure where to start.